# What does the ".Configure()" call do in Fluent.Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

What does the ".Configure()" call do in Fluent.Azure? Is it required? If I include it in the code (like below) it doesn't return, it just sits and blocks.

But it is used in MS's examples:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-dotnet-manage-storage-connections-for-web-apps/blob/master/Program.cs

```
var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
    .Configure()
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithDefaultSubscription()
    ;
```

[Edit]
Here are the packages I was referencing:
[image: nuget fluent]

[image: nuget Rest.ClientRuntime]

I "was" referencing them because I have since upgraded two of the packages to fix this issue (even though the ones I referenced were within the range specified in the nuget package):  [Any command on Fluent.Azure Results in "Method not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838079/any-command-on-fluent-azure-results-in-method-not-found)

As for what happens, .Configure() never returns. The code stops and blocks on that line. (Or at least I think it's that line because when I remove it it works.) When I have them enabled, it will throw an exception about the thread being locked up, too, but I disabled those and it didn't return after several hours, when it's very quick without that line of code.

Comment: Please let us know which nuget package(and their versions) are you using? And what do you mean it it just sits and blocks, it blocks at the .Configure()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'd better provide a completed sample code, and the nuget packages you're using as well as their versions.

Here, I'm using [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent, version 1.34.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/).

Regarding `What does the ".Configure()" call do in Fluent.Azure? Is it required?`, After going through the source code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/bb8324aeae5519b9e99f7beb63ef37c2db815277/src/ResourceManagement/Azure.Fluent/Azure.cs#L757), the `Configure()` method is used to return an `IConfigurable` instance, and then `IConfigurable` instance calls the `Authenticate(credentials)` method([source code here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/Azure.Fluent/Azure.cs#L929)).

Actually, the `Configure()` method is not required, you can directly call the `Authenticate(credentials)` method(source code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/Azure.Fluent/Azure.cs#L736)).

I'm not sure why it sits and blocks at your side, unless you provide more details as I mentioned previously. I did test with/without .Configure(), either of them can work well.

Here is a screenshot of debug with `.Configure()` method:

[image]