# Any command on Fluent.Azure Results in "Method not found"

Tags: c#, azure

Any command on Fluent.Azure results in a "Method not found" exception.

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
> Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials..ctor(Microsoft.Rest.ITokenProvider,
> System.String, System.String)'.

Looking it up online and there isn't a constructor like that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.rest.tokencredentials.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet

I am creating the azure object like so, and it seems to be working.

```
var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithDefaultSubscription()
    ;
```

But as soon as I try either of the following commands, I get this exception:

```
var l = await azure.VirtualMachines.ListAsync();
    
var webapp = azure.WebApps.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, name);
```

I'm referencing v. 1.34.0 of Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent for .NET 4.7.2.

[image: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent on Nuget]

And it has these dependencies:

[image: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent dependencies]

And my references do fall within these ranges:

[image: referenced dependencies]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime to 2.3.21 and Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication to 2.4.1 seems to have resolved myissue.