# How can i get a list of services in Azure using c#?

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to get a list of app services in Azure using the following , in a winforms app.

```
 string clientId = "your_client_id";
 string clientSecret = "your_client_secret";
 string tenantId = "your_tenant_id";
 string subscriptionId = "your_subscription_id";

 var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, 
 clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
 var azure = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

But the error i get is that:

```
 "The type or namespace Configure does not exists in the namesapce Azure"
```

I have  installed the namespace Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent with Nuget packages and no difference .
How can i fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the ".Configure()" call do in Fluent.Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62837607/what-does-the-configure-call-do-in-fluent-azure)

Comment: A bit of help pls , so how would i modify my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be running into an issue with conflicting NuGet packages.

Try using the fully-qualified class name like this:

```
var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
    .Configure()
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` SDK package is deprecated. The suggested alternative is [Azure.ResourceManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager/).

Alternatively, you can achieve your requirement using `Azure.ResourceManager.ResourceGraph` this sdk package provides the ability to effectively query at scale across a given set of subscriptions. Sample code is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/first-query-dotnet). Hope this helps.